# Does openGL ES have trouble displaying text?

Tags: iphone, text, opengl-es

Someone told me that openGL is for graphic only, and that it's very bad at displaying good readable text. Is that true for openGL ES on iPhone OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render any of the iPhone fonts into a texture and if it's displayed one-to-one, it looks beautiful.