# Is openGL ES on iPhone fast enough to render text that consists of little images?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

For some very sophisticated graphics I am thinking about making a fontset out of image files. Do the openGL ES experienced people here think that this would be okay on iphone, or does performance go down quickly with this?

The amount of text to be displayed is not that much. At max I would say as long as my question text here, for example.

Comment: "The amount of text to be displayed is not that much. At max I would say as long as my question text here, for example."   — Including or excluding that line? ☺

Comment: You really should have asked this as part of your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132360/does-opengl-es-have-trouble-displaying-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how the AtlasLabel and AtlasSprite work in the Cocos2d library, and it can hit 60 frames a second. It does it by putting all the different images into one image file and then rendering all the characters triangles from the same texture.